# fastshap: Error in UseMethod("explain") : no applicable method for 'explain' applied to an object of class "xgb.Booster"

Tags: r, xgboost, shap

After fitting a xgboost model (model_n) I try to run the code below to obtain shap-values, where trainval is a dataframe with my traindata without the Y variabele:

```
shap_values <- explain(model_n, X = trainval)
```

I receive this error:

```
[[Error in UseMethod("explain") : 
  no applicable method for 'explain' applied to an object of class ["xgb.Booster"]]
```

If I use this line:

```
shap_values <- fastshap::explain(model_n, X = trainval)
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in explain.default(object, feature_names = feature_names, X = X,  : 
  argument "pred_wrapper" is missing, with no default
```

I have also tried with trainval as a matrix although this gives the same error.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are two problems here i think: 1. you need to pass a "predictor wrapper" function to tell the explain function what to predict based on, and 2. fastshap does not like dataframes, use matrices if possible. see https://bgreenwell.github.io/fastshap/articles/fastshap.html

Comment: Correction: data.frame is fine, fastshap does not like X to be a tibble. Just pass X = as.data.frame(trainval) instead. I think I will write a more lengthy answer for this later.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `library(vip)` besides `library(fastshap)` to my code did solve the issue for using `shap_values <- fastshap::explain(model_n, X = trainval)`

Answer (score 0):

`fastshap` is a good tool, but not a super-easy one. You need to pass a *prediction function* called `pred_wrap` so the fastshap explainer knows how to generate new predictions from your model.

Example code taken from https://bgreenwell.github.io/fastshap/articles/fastshap.html :

```
# Prediction wrapper
pfun <- function(object, newdata) {
  predict(object, data = newdata)$predictions
}

# Compute fast (approximate) Shapley values using 10 Monte Carlo repetitions
system.time({  # estimate run time
  set.seed(5038)
  shap <- explain(rfo, X = X, pred_wrapper = pfun, nsim = 10)
})
```

Also, if you are working with xgboost specifically the `SHAPforxgboost` package may be friendlier: https://liuyanguu.github.io/post/2019/07/18/visualization-of-shap-for-xgboost/

Finally the [vip](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vip/versions/0.3.2) package is not a replacement for fastshap. It's a framework which contains many *variable importance* metrics and *plots* for them. Including, but not limited to shapley.